# Why does an implicit object have higher precedence than an implicit val in Scala companion objects?

Tags: scala

I have been playing around with this small example to try to get a better overview of how scala resolves implicits. I just discovered a difference between declaring an implicit object and an implicit val in the companion object.

The type class named "Evidence[-B]" in the example is contravariant; e.g. an Evidence[Base] can be used where a Evidence[Derived] is required.

I have tried to compile the code below with Scala 2.11.7:

```
trait Evidence[-B] {
  def hello(input: B): String
}

trait Base
object Base {
  implicit object BaseEvidence extends Evidence[Base] {
    override def hello(input: Base): String = "Evidence[Base] from implicit object"
  }
}

class Derived extends Base
object Derived {
  implicit val derivedEvidence: Evidence[Derived] = new Evidence[Derived] {
    override def hello(input: Derived): String = "Evidence[Derived] from implicit val"
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  def hello[A](input: A)(implicit ev: Evidence[A]): Unit = {
    println(ev.hello(input))
  }
  hello(new Derived)
}
```

However, the compiler gives an error "ambiguous implicit values":

```
Error:(24, 8) ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BaseEvidence in object Base of type Base.BaseEvidence.type
 and value derivedEvidence in object Derived of type => Evidence[Derived]
 match expected type Evidence[Derived]
  hello(new Derived)

   ^
```

From my understanding of the implicit resolution rules, the companion object of `Derived`should be searched first; then the companion object of the base class `Base`.

When changing the implicit val derivedEvidence to an implicit object, the code compiles:

```
object Derived {
  implicit object DerivedEvidence extends Evidence[Derived] {
    override def hello(input: Derived): String = "Evidence[Derived] from implicit object"
}
```

What is the reason for this behavior?